# Trouble plotting 2 charts in 1 row - dash plotly

Tags: python, html, plotly

I'm trying to build a dashboard that shows 2 charts on the same row. I am using both `dbc.Row` and `dbc.Col` to divide the sections but I'm not sure what is wrong with the code as the charts are displaying on top of each other instead of side by side. I have tried adding `style={"width": "45%", "margin-top": "1%","margin-left": "0%", "margin-right": "0%"}` and opposite to the second chart but still just shows the charts on separate rows.

```
html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-1', multi=True, value=('EC'),
                             options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                                      for x in sorted(dfdate['Campaign'].unique())]),
                dcc.Graph(id='date-graph', figure=fig_cpa_date),
            ]), width={'size': 3}
        ),
        dbc.Col(
            html.Div([
                dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-2', multi=True, value=('EC'), style={"margin-top": "1%"},
                             options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                                      for x in sorted(dfdate['Campaign'].unique())]),
                dcc.Graph(id='spend-graph', figure=fig_spend),
            ]), width={'size': 3}
        ),
    ]),
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, changing the html.Div([]) for just the children[] of the Col:

```
dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col(
        children=[
                    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-1', multi=True, value = ('EC'),
                    options= [{'label': x, 'value': x} 
                    for x in sorted (dfdate['Campaign'].unique())]),
                    dcc.Graph(id='date-graph', figure=fig_cpa_date),
                ], width=3
            ),
    dbc.Col(
        children=[
                    dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-2', multi=True, value=('EC'), style={"margin-top": "1%"},
                    options=[{'label': x, 'value': x}
                    for x in sorted(dfdate['Campaign'].unique())]),
                    dcc.Graph(id='spend-graph', figure=fig_spend),
                ], width=3
            ),
        ]),
```